# xamarin.forms facebook login windows phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

i'm been using [xamarin.auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) to use facebook in my app for android and iOS. but now i need to make it for windows phone, how do you recommend to do this for windows phone? is there a xamarin component that you like, or a tutorial you normally use of this?

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Auth has Windows Phone support. Just download experimental-winphone branch (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/experimental-winphone)

Comment: can figure out how it's works. an can't find any docs for this, only for the android and ios

Comment: Wait, just found a sample. gonna check it out

Comment: okay, i tried it now, can't seems to find a way to import the lib where the OAuth2Authenticator class is. how can you add this to the refs`?

Comment: I didn't understand you question. Can you clarify it? It works just the same as iOS/Android Xamarin.Auth

Comment: I can't add it to my project.

Comment: Did you build it? Did you add dll's as references?

Comment: Build it. But couldn't find any dlls

Comment: Did you clone specific branch? You must do `git clone -b experimental-winphone https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth.git`

Comment: Nope. Never done that before. Not sure how its works. Allways download as zip

Comment: Okay. tried it. First thing, it can't load a package named mircosoft.bcl.build.1.0.7, i should be able to add this myself, but i can't locate the package anywhere, only 1.0.1 versions.

Comment: I found that the refs. need a update, an everything works.